# What is something that is a strong acid and a strong reducing agent, but not a reducing agent because of the conjugate base of that acid?

Tags: acid-base

So 2 answers I am not looking for is HI and formic acid. Although both of them are acids, HI and formic acid are not doing the reducing, but their conjugate forms, I- and HCOO- are doing the reducing, after protonation.

However, I would expand this question to also looking for other examples besides HI and formic acid analogies. Already taken that HCl and HBr being too weak of reducers. So therefore who else besides HI and formic acid in that category.

If the answer is, there isn't any, I would find that interesting knowing that something that is a strong base and a strong oxidizing agents exist, but without a conjugate acid form of that base. By that I mean, strong base medium-strong oxidizer or medium-strong base strong oxidizers exist, without the conjugate acid form.

Comment: How could be HI or HCOOH (or their anions) strong oxidizing agents? // You should finally learn some thorough elaboration of your questions, including compact results of prior research. Your questions often seem to be made from the same, rather weird question template.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  down-voting or closure.

Comment: @Poutnik oh whoops, I realized I said oxidizer in the topic, but in the body I said reducer, it's fixed.

Comment: Try to reformulate your question to be clear, it looks rather like a puzzle. Topics may be puzzles, but questions should not be. And elaborate it. If you do not put enough effort to formulate the question text, why to expect responders would put enough effort to their answers?

Comment: Poutnik, I explained they're not both at the same time. HI and formic acid are only reducers once they lose their protons 1st, become I- and HCOO-, But then, they're no longer acids.

Comment: @Mithoron that's the acidity part, once they lose their protons, then they're now reducing agents.

Comment: He means for the conjugate pair HA/A-, HA being strong acid and a strong reducing agent on its own, not indirectly because of  A- being the reducing agent. But to have any HA, it must be very concebtrated up to waterless. / /  A- will be generally always  stronger reducing agens than HA and vice versa for oxidation.

Comment: Usually acidic solutions behave as oxidant for metals M. Zinc, magnesium or iron are oxidized in acidic solutions, by the famous reaction $$\ce{M + 2 H+ -> M^{2+} + H2}$$ where $\ce{M}$ can be $\ce{Zn, Mg}$ or $\ce{ Fe}$

Comment: @Maurice But OP search of an acid as a direct reductant.

Comment: Strong acid means there only its conjugate base present, so the strong acid cannot do any reduction. And it's base is always better reductant, anyway.

Comment: Something like HCo(CO)4 would be my guess, but I have no idea how good a reducing agent it actually is, and with a pKa of 1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_carbonyl_hydride) some might debate if it is a strong acid.

Comment: IF Neal only spent all the time wasted by debating/rewriting/reopening rather on proper elaboration of his questions before posting them.....

Answer (score 2):

Though I perceive the formulation of the question would benefit a revision for clarity, an answer constrained to the first half to the title of your question can hint to ascorbic acid (often named vitamin C):

[image]

For one, it is not an organic acid with a carboxylic group.  However, by its first $\text{p}K_a = 4.10$ ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemistry_of_ascorbic_acid)), this compound is a little bit more acidic, than acetic acid ($\text{p}K_a = 4.756$, [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetic_acid)).

Second, it is a known antioxidant of high relevance in (e.g. food) technology and biochemistry both in one- as well as two-electron redox reactions.  Hence it is not surprising ascorbic acid (and its derivatives) was of research interest for long time, and still is (e.g. [1, 2]).  Here, the motif of enediones adjacent to carbonyl group can yield a diketone,  a characteristic feature of the [reductones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductone).

[image]

(credit to Boorsook and Keighley, 1933)

[1] Borsook, H.; Keighley, G. Oxidation-Reduction Potential of Ascorbic Acid (Vitamin C). *PNAS* **1933**, *19*, 875–878. [doi 10.1073/pnas.19.9.875](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.19.9.875) (by now available as open access).

[2] Matsui, T.; Kitagawa, Y.; Okumura, M.; Shigeta, Y. Accurate Standard Hydrogen Electrode Potential and Applications to the Redox Potentials of Vitamin C and NAD/NADH. *J. Phys. Chem. A* **2015**, *119*, 369–376. [doi 10.1021/jp508308y](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp508308y).

Comment: But I think AA is antioxidant due its anion. Its solution is more or less stable for hours, I guess. But if alkalized by NaOH, it gets intense yellow within dozens of seconds or few minutes.

Comment: I was already aware of ascorbic acid, but speaking of that, does anyone know what's the name of the tetrahydrofuran ring of ascorbic acid? Tetrahydrofuran is if it has no double bonds, whereas furan has 2 double bonds but in different locations from ascorbic acid.

Comment: I would name the ring as a lactone ring. And the idea of the antioxidant action coming from the anion is right; blood pH is three units above the pKa.

Comment: @NealConroy Based on a *similarity search* in the [Wikipedia structure explorer](https://wikipedia.cheminfo.org/), the of [2-furanone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Furanone) is an other one (includes the C=O, more than merely [2,5-dihydrofuran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,5-Dihydrofuran)).

Answer (score 0):

The best definition of acids and bases are electron pair acceptors-acids and electron pair donors-bases. These reactions can be considered as 2-electron redox reactions or possibly a quick two step one electron transfers. Redox reactions take this one step lower to one electron transfers, indeed most redox reactions are probably a sequential set of one electron transfers. My point is that the two types of reactions are hopelessly intertwined.

Oxidative or reductive strengths are relative. Your requirements are confusing. Possibilities that might match your criteria are the intermediate oxidation states of elements such as chlorine, nitrogen and sulfur and the metals in the first transition series, especially manganese and chromium. Their reactions can be a complicated mix of acid-base reactions and electron transfers.